# get android AsyncHttpClient response after it finish

Tags: android, rest, android-async-http

hello i am using `AsyncHttpClient` to send request to `restful` api 
the problem is i want to have the result in `onSuccess` and pass it from the class who have this method to my activity

```
public int send(JSONObject parameters,String email,String password){
      int i =0;
    try {
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(parameters.toString());
        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        client.setBasicAuth(email,password);
        client.post(context, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/webapi/add", entity, "application/json",
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(
                                    new String(responseBody));
                            i=statusCode;
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return i;
}
```

of course i always get `i=0`; because it's `Async` method
i tried to make the method send `void` and make a callback inside onSuccess but that produce a lot of problems with the activity (that's another question i will ask later)
so do you have a way to get the value of i as statusCode?
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to make the method send void and make a callback inside onSuccess

The method being void is good.

Making a callback inside onSuccess can look like this

Add a callback interface

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void onResponse(T response);
}
```

Use it as a parameter and make the method void

```
public void send(
    JSONObject parameters, 
    String email,
    String password, 
    final Callback<Integer> callback) // Add this
```

Then, inside the `onSuccess` method, when you get the result do

```
if (callback != null) {
    callback.onResponse(statusCode);
}
```

Outside that method, where you call `send`, create anonymous callback class

```
webServer.send(json, "email", "password", new Callback<Integer>() {
    public void onResponse(Integer response) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Not sure why you are returning a response code, though. Should you return the JSONObject?